# Add readonly attributes (getters) to NSManagedObject

Tags: core-data, rubymotion, magicalrecord

I have a ruby class and a match definition in core data.
There is a NSData field 'image_data' to store my image.
In my ruby class, i was thinking to add a getter to return an UIImage.
However, i get an error saying "undefined method `image' for #"

What do i need to do to get around this?

```
class ActivityImage < NSManagedObject

  def image
     UIImage.imageWithData(image_data)
  end

end
```

Comment: How are you calling `image`?  Is the object's class `ActivityImage` or `NSManagedObject`?

Comment: activityImage is created using MR_createInContext
and i just call activityImage.image

activity_image_item_cell.rb:41:in `item=:': undefined method `image' for #<NSManagedObject_ActivityImage_:0x951dd60> (NoMethodError)
 from journal_controller.rb:1:in `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:'
myjournal[1761:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NoMethodError', reason: 'activity_image_item_cell.rb:41:in `item=:': undefined method `image' for #<NSManagedObject_ActivityImage_:0x951dd60> (NoMethodError)
 from journal_controller.rb:1:in `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:'

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is a way of creating a ["Transformable Attribute"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdNSAttributes.html).

If you read through that guide, you'll get to understand what transformable attributes are, hopefully you're using Xcode's model editor so you can just create the attribute in there, but otherwise you'll just have to pull some hackery to get the entity then create the image attribute and set it as transformable.